# How do I make PIL take into account the shortest side when creating a thumbnail?

Tags: python, image, math, python-imaging-library, resize

Currently, for my function below...the image will be resized based on the longest side.

Basically the image has a larger height, the height will be 200px. The width will be just...whatever...

If the image has a larger width, the width will be 200px, and the height will adjust accordingly.

How do I flip this around!? I want this function to take into account the shortest side.

**Am I writing this function incorrectly??**

```
def create_thumbnail(f, width=200, height=None, pad = False):
    #resizes the longest side!!! doesn't even care about the shortest side
    #this function maintains aspect ratio.
    if height==None: height=width
    im = Image.open(StringIO(f))
    imagex = int(im.size[0])
    imagey = int(im.size[1])
    if imagex < width or imagey < height:
        pass
        #return None
    if im.mode not in ('L', 'RGB', 'RGBA'):
        im = im.convert('RGB')
    im.thumbnail((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumbnail_file = StringIO()
    im.save(thumbnail_file, 'JPEG')
    thumbnail_file.seek(0)
    return thumbnail_file
```

Comment: if you base it on the shorter side, then the longer side will be truncated, is that what you want?

Comment: do you want to maintain aspect ratio?

Comment: Yes, I would like aspect ratio to be maintained. However, I want the shortest side to take priority.  This means that if the picture is 600x400, I want the 400 side to be down to 200. Right now, the 600 goes to 200.

Comment: What happens if the picture is 200x20000? It sounds like you want to keep it in the original size, but then that certainly won't fit in the spot where you want a thumbnail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `resize` instead of `thumbnail`.

The point behind `thumbnail` is to make it easy to scale an image down to fit within a particular bounding box preserving aspect ratio. That means that if your bounding box is a square, the longer side of the image determines the scale used.

`resize` gives you more direct control -- you specify exactly what size you want.

Actually, since you want to preserve aspect you could still use thumbnail, but you need to fudge the bounding box. Before your call to `thumbnail`, try doing this:

```
old_aspect = float(imagex)/float(imagey)
new_aspect = float(width)/float(height)
if old_aspect < new_aspect:
  height = int(width / old_aspect)
else:
  width = int(height * old_aspect)
```

Answer (score 1):

i put together this function a while ago:

```
def thumbnail(img, size=150):

    from math import floor
    from PIL import Image

    img = img.copy()

    if img.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
        img = img.convert('RGB')

    width, height = img.size

    if width == height:
        img.thumbnail((size, size), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    elif height > width:
        ratio = float(width) / float(height)
        newwidth = ratio * size
        img = img.resize((int(floor(newwidth)), size), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    elif width > height:
        ratio = float(height) / float(width)
        newheight = ratio * size
        img = img.resize((size, int(floor(newheight))), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    return img

image = thumbnail(image, size=600)
```

it resizes an image down to at most size on its longest size preserving aspect ratio